# Oracle using the like comparison taken from function in value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a simple function that takes in 3 parameters, 2 numbers and a string. I have written the function but am not getting the expected results from a simple select statement when using the LIKE comparison for the string.

The select from the function below returns no rows when executed with the string input value set to ebts, but if I run this as a standalone select state it returns 2 rows which what I would expect.  Have used dbms output to determine if whitespace were being passed but all looks OK.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OPC_OP.sitezone_exists
    (in_site_id IN NUMBER, in_zone_id IN NUMBER, in_mod VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS

v_count_rec NUMBER;
v_return NUMBER;
v_mod VARCHAR2(4) := in_mod;


BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO v_count_rec
FROM AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS
WHERE AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.site_id = in_site_id
AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.zone_id = in_zone_id
AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module LIKE 'v_mod%';


IF v_count_rec > 0
THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('count'||v_count_rec||'=========='||v_mod||'=============');
    v_return:= 1;
    RETURN (v_return);
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('count'||v_count_rec||'=========='||v_mod||'=============');
    v_return:= 0;
    RETURN (v_return);
END IF;

END sitezone_exists;
```

When passing in values 12, 12, ebts the output displayed is:

count 0  ==========ebts=============
RetVal = 0

If I run the same select subtituting only passing in the above values the query returns 2 rows - I have removed the like clause of the function and it then returns 2 rows, any idea why the like part of clause is failing to match with rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to match a string literal with this:

```
AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module LIKE 'v_mod%';
```

Change it to:

```
AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module LIKE v_mod||'%';
```

Answer (score 2):

MarioAna has the right answer, IMO, but as an aside (which is too long for a comment), your function can be better written.

You're duplicating the dbms_output code, plus it's considered best practice to have a single `RETURN` in a function (although I would argue that more might be ok - one in the body and one per exception in the exception block...), so you could rewrite it as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OPC_OP.sitezone_exists
    (in_site_id IN NUMBER, in_zone_id IN NUMBER, in_mod VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS

  v_count_rec NUMBER;
  v_return NUMBER;
  v_mod VARCHAR2(4) := in_mod;

BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO   v_count_rec
  FROM   AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS aaa
  WHERE  aaa.site_id = in_site_id
  AND    aaa.zone_id = in_zone_id
  AND    aaa.module LIKE v_mod||'%';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('count '||v_count_rec||'=========='||v_mod||'=============');

  IF v_count_rec > 0 THEN 
    v_return := 1;
  ELSE
    v_return:= 0;
  END IF;

  RETURN (v_return);

END sitezone_exists;
/
```

Comment: MarioAna - Thanks thanks for your prompt answer much appriceated - first time I've posted on this site this worked and has saved me wasting more time.  Boneist thanks for the advise, makes perfect sence.